# Does puppetlabs/ntp work for windows 10/server?

Tags: windows, puppet, ntp, foreman

I am working with puppet and foreman as puppet UI. Trying to sync NTP module with windows agent. It does not work. But it works with Linux centos7 and ubuntu agent.
Does anyone guide me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The puppetlabs/ntp module's page [on the Forge](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/ntp) does not list any version of Windows among the supported operating systems.  The [Puppet PE supported modules page](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/about/supported#compat-matrix) also appears to indicate that puppetlabs/ntp does not support Windows.  As far as I can tell, if you want to use Puppet to manage Windows time synchronization configuration then you need to use a different module or roll your own.

And rolling your own might be your best alternative.  I find only [one likely module](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/ncorrare/windowstime) on the forge, but it is quite old, does not claim to support recent versions of Puppet, and has a low quality score.  It might nevertheless serve your purpose just fine, but if not, then I'm inclined to guess that you won't get much help from the developer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try https://forge.puppet.com/modules/tse/winntp that is the module used in the labs in the official Puppet training courses.